# Is there a way to increment a variable within a single-lined for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Given the following definitions

```
layerData = [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]

bias = [0.47, -0.45, 0.31, -0.09, 0.21 ,-0.18, 0.14, -0.45, -0.39, -0.14]
```

Starting at the head of the `bias` list, for each element `N` in `layerData` I would like to take the next `N` elements from `bias` and append that list to the result

This is what it should output:

```
[[0.47, -0.45, 0.31], [-0.09, 0.21, -0.18], [0.14, -0.45], [-0.39], [-0.14]]
```

Comment: What is ``row``? Why not use ``bias[j]``?

Comment: What you have here is a "list comprehension"; while it uses the `for` keyword, it has its own semantics and is different from a regular for loop.

Comment: j does not increase by 1. I don't have something to do this so I just put row.

Comment: ...speaking to the code you're writing, though... this looks like a use case for `enumerate`, or otherwise finding a different construct that doesn't _require_ you to do an assignment.

Comment: Is your goal to increment ``row``, or to partition ``bias`` according to ``layerData``? Do you actually need this as a list comprehension?

Comment: A list comprehension **is not a single-lined for loop**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an iterator - call `next` on it each time you want a value.

```
>>> bias = [0.47, -0.45, 0.31, -0.09, 0.21 ,-0.18, 0.14, -0.45, -0.39, -0.14]
>>> layerData = [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
>>> it = iter(bias)
>>> [[next(it) for _ in range(n)] for n in layerData]
[[0.47, -0.45, 0.31], [-0.09, 0.21, -0.18], [0.14, -0.45], [-0.39], [-0.14]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) for a running total of `layerData`. This allows to extract the sub-list directly as slices instead of individual items:

```py
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>>
>>> layerData = [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
>>> bias = [0.47, -0.45, 0.31, -0.09, 0.21 ,-0.18, 0.14, -0.45, -0.39, -0.14]
>>>
>>> [bias[i-n:i] for i, n in zip(accumulate(layerData), layerData)]
[[0.47, -0.45, 0.31], [-0.09, 0.21, -0.18], [0.14, -0.45], [-0.39], [-0.14]]
```